# How to set wordpress theme in code

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed a wordpress theme to my website but there was an error in the code which meant I could not use /wp-admin to set another theme for some reason.  I then tried deleting the theme from wp-content but that didn't work.  Where in all the wordpress files can I change the theme programatically?

Comment: this link will help you http://www.inkthemes.com/wordpress-database-theme-change/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look in the file error_log.

Restore back your applied theme and check error_log for the possible error that is causing wordpress to die.

Or if you are unable to fix the error open database select the database wordpress is using (open wp-config.php for reference to database name)

Change the theme name in options table, that's it

come back to admin panel and it should be working